# Will two I/O operations trying to access same file cause race condition in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, promise

I want to create two directories.
1. /tmp/xyz/dir1
2. /tmp/xyz/dir2

I'm promisifying `fs.mkdir` as `mkdirPromisified` and then :

```
let mkdirProcesses = [];
mkdirProcesses.push(mkdirPromisifed('/tmp/xyz/dir1'));
mkdirProcesses.push(mkdirPromisifed('/tmp/xyz/dir2'));
return Promise.all(mkdirProcesses);
```

What exactly will this code do? Since I/O in JavaScript is asynchronous, I'm assuming this will create two threads at the OS level, or is my assumption wrong? If not, will these two threads try to access the same base directory structure ('/tmp/xyz') at the same time and cause a race condition? If so, what is a better solution to accomplish what I'm trying to do? The number of directories I want to create is not static.

Comment: Node doesn't really have race conditions, `fs` will be able to create both directories just fine. The problem would occur if you were trying to create a directory depending on another directory first being created, and both calls was async.

Comment: @adeneo I'm pretty sure node also would not like two concurrent calls to `fs.writeFile` on the same locations

Comment: @Bergi - probably not, that's what streams are for.